# Running fbs freeze binary causes segmentation fault; MacOs, python

Tags: pyqt, fbs

Using fbs to compile PyQt5 python GUI into a runnable app. Running Mac M1 v12.6. Of course, this is my first python GUI, so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong here.

`fbs run` launches the program without issue. Everything works.

`fbs freeze` finishes successfully. But, running the binary generated in `/target` always results in `zsh: segmentation fault`.

The program seems to fail when creating `ApplicationContext()`. Testing this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( 'Hope for earth!' )
    appctxt = ApplicationContext()
    print( 'Salvation!' )
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    exit_code = appctxt.app.exec_()
    sys.exit(exit_code)
```

When running in IDE (PyCharm CE) or with `fbs run`, I get sweet sweet `Salvation!`. When running the binary, I get only `Hope for earth!`.

I create `main` as described in the fbs tutorial, here: https://github.com/mherrmann/fbs-tutorial

The troubleshooting page (https://build-system.fman.io/troubleshooting) suggests to run freeze with a debug flag to check for errors:

```
fbs clean
fbs freeze --debug
```

Full output has a couple of warnings, but no exceptions or errors.

All testing is done with a fresh and active conda environment in Python 3.6. The only packages installed:

`conda install pyserial`
`pip install pyqt5 fbs`

Also tried to run the binary when freezing an alternate version of `main`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print( 'Close, but...' )
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    print( 'no cigar!' )
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Again - this runs with `fbs run`, but fails at `QApplication` using the binary from `fbs freeze`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with pyinstaller included with fbs. Unfortunately, fbs is limited to python 3.6.

When running pyinstaller for python 3.6 (not part of fbs), `pyinstaller my_app.py` throws many errors related to `libSystem.B.dylib` . Not sure why I don't see these errors while packinging with fbs.

Running `pyinstaller my_app.py` (not part of fbs) with python 3.9 or 3.10 compiles everything just fine.